# phonegap - textfield validation in HTML 5

Tags: html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have a running website and I'm building an app for it using jQuery mobile. I validate the textfields on the webpage using HTML 5 required option. it works fine on browsers and ripple emulator but after I compiled the app and tested on a device it doesn't validate like it did on the webpage

```
<input name="firstname" type="text" id="firstname" size="40" required="required" placeholder="Firstname" />

<input name="lastname" type="text" id="lastname" size="40" required="required" placeholder="Lastname" />
```

any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume here that you used iOS or Android (below 4.4.4), which neither support the *required*. You can check what all is supported per device on [Can I use](http://caniuse.com/#search=required).